# Android transition rotate animation

Tags: android, animation, transition

I'm searching that how to make a view in activity A transform to view in activity B and rotate it. Like the link below:

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfdOpF3dMuU&feature=youtu.be)

Hope someone can show me the way to do it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared Element Transition's + Rotate as Enter transition

[Here](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/how-to-use-material-transitions-in-fragment-transactions-5a62b9d0b26b) example is for fade, you can replace it with rotate

Comment: Dear Ablu Moallim, I know but shared element does not have rotation transition (just scale in/out or move to position that transitionname of each element is defined). So that is my problem, I want the element can smoothly show detail and rotate to 90 degrees without set orientation of activity (my application always set portrait mode). You can see in my posted video below.

Comment: I have update my answer. You can use TransitionSet + Enter Animation

Comment: Sorry, but this example link below is used for fragments, and my problem is between 2 activities. My source activity code:

`options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                activity,
                new Pair<>(views[0], activity.getString(transitionCode))
        );
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());`

Answer (score 0):

You should create anim folder in your res folder, then create rotate.xml file in anim folder and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1200"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="90" />
```

and in your activity on your desired widget, add below code:

```
  yourView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate));
```

Comment: Dear Salman, the problem is I want the animation tranform from source activity and rotate until the des activity and stop at 90 degrees as the link I mentioned above, like shared element transition between activities but additional more rotation animation.